# How to make an attribute the sum of 2 attributes in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a database called Results which is the results of votes for a specific question. Now my question is if it is possible to do an attribute in a table were the attribute is the sum of 2 other attributes. Example:
The attributes are for the database are:

> Yes Votes
>   No Votes
>   Abstain Votes
>   Total Voters (number of people who voted)

```
CREATE TABLE `results` (
 `result_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `count_yes` int(3),
 `count_no` int(3),
 `count_abstain` int(3), 
 `total_voters` *Default sum of yes no and abstain votes*,
  UNIQUE (result_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not calculate that on-the-fly when you select the data?

Comment: 1 out of 3. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query for the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways to do this and have it as a table/view object:

**Method 1: Create a view**
This works on all versions of MySQL. You create a view with the extra column that sums the votes up, like so:

```
CREATE VIEW `results_view` AS
SELECT
    result_id,
    COALESCE(count_yes, 0) AS count_yes,
    COALESCE(count_no, 0) AS count_no,
    COALESCE(count_abstain, 0) AS count_abstain,
    (COALESCE(count_yes, 0) + COALESCE(count_no, 0) + COALESCE(count_abstain, 0)) as total_voters
;
```

Note the use of `COALESCE(..., 0)` to ensure that you cast your `NULL` values to zero. Any mathemtical sum with a `NULL` in MySQL equates to `NULL`. i.e. `NULL + 2` = `NULL`.

**Method 2: Use a generated column in your base table**
This works in MySQL v5.7.6+. You redefine your table statement as:

```
CREATE TABLE `results` (
 `result_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `count_yes` int(3),
 `count_no` int(3),
 `count_abstain` int(3), 
 `total_voters` int(3) AS (COALESCE(count_yes, 0) + COALESCE(count_no, 0) + COALESCE(count_abstain, 0)),
  UNIQUE (result_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Note the column `total_voters`. MySQL calls this a generated column, though other flavours of SQL tend to call it a calculated column.

If you have an existing table, you can simply add the column, like so:

```
ALTER TABLE `results` ADD COLUMN `total_voters` int(3) AS (COALESCE(count_yes, 0) + COALESCE(count_no, 0) + COALESCE(count_abstain, 0));
```

Comment: How would u insert it in this case?

Comment: Just like you'd insert into the regular table that doesn't have the column, you'd only list the columns `result_id`, `count_yes`, `count_no`, and `count_abstain`. The other column would be automatically calculated.

Answer (score 1):

You should [create a View](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) to calculate the extra `total_voters` column.

```
CREATE VIEW total_voters_view AS
SELECT result_id,
count_yes,
count_no,
count_abstain,
(count_yes + count_no + count_abstain) as total_voters
FROM results;
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the count of the rows in your source table. That should give you a value for `total_voters` which you can insert into the results table. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM source_table`. I could help you better if you provide the schema of your source table.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL 5.7.6 or newer, you can use [Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

```
CREATE TABLE `results` (
 `result_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `count_yes` int(3),
 `count_no` int(3),
 `count_abstain` int(3), 
 `total_voters` INT(3) AS count_yes + count_no + count_abstain,
  UNIQUE (result_id)
)
```